# Different pixel information in PIL and cv2

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have load the same image using both `PIL` and `cv2`, but the pixel information is different for the same index. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread('Fruits1.jpg') # Can be many different formats.
print(img[100, 200])

img = Image.open('Fruits1.jpg')
pixel_img = img.load()
print(pixel_img[100, 200])
```

Output:

```
[191 212 209]
(255, 255, 255)
```

Shouldn't the numbers of RGB channels be the same both cases? This is the image I used.
 [image]

Comment: Probably easier to advise if you share your image.

Comment: I have added the image with the question. @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenCV returns a numpy array. Your indexing thus is [row_idx, col_idx], or [y, x] whereas PIL pixel access is the exact opposite, using [x, y] coordinates.

Flip the PIL access to [200, 100] to see the same pixel.

Careful, there will be another confusion: PIL reads the channels in RGB order, but OpenCV reads them in BGR!